# issue with While statement

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I am trying to pull HEADLINES.. that I have saved in a DB, they all have unique IDs.. I need a way to be able to call them but type or ID for instance.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE type = 'sports'");
$stmt->execute();

while($rfr=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
?>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <img src="<?php echo $rfr['folder'] . $rfr1['file'];?>.jpg" >
      <h2><?php echo $rfr['headline'];?></h2>
      <p>V.A. conducts study to determine effectiveness</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read More &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <img src="imgs/news/n4.jpg">
      <h2><?php echo $rfr['headline'];?></h2>
      <p>The Rev. Daniel Berrigan, a Roman Catholic priest and peace activist who was imprisoned for burning draft files in a protest against the Vietnam War, died Saturday. He was 94.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read More &raquo;</a></p>
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <img src="imgs/news/n1.jpg">
      <h2><?php echo $rfr['headline'];?></h2>
      <p>President Barack Obama is getting one more chance to poke fun at fellow politicians, the press and himself at the annual White House Correspondents' Dinner.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read More &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
 <?php
  }
  ?>
```

Every time I run this code though.. It just enters only the headline from ID 1 everytime. and it makes a ton of duplicate post..

I want it to select through all the headlines in that type.. thats why im using the WHILE()

Comment: The `while` loops through all records where the `type` is `sports`. Executing at the DB level doesn't produce the same results? Maybe your looking for `distinct` or `group by`..

Comment: Just as a side note, you can do `<?php while (..): ?>` (note the `:` instead of `{`, and close the loop with `<?php endwhile; ?>` instead of `}` -- can be a bit nicer and clearer when templating!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE type = 'sports'");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $rfr) {
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img src="<?php echo $rfr['folder'] . $rfr1['file'];?>.jpg" >
        <h2><?php echo $rfr['headline'];?></h2>
        <p>V.A. conducts study to determine effectiveness</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Read More &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>

    ...
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: that foreach does not work... I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /nfs/c11/h05/mnt/=/domains/concept/html/temp3/.php on line 121 I cant even correct it.

Comment: I also just got this Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_result() in /nfs/c11/h05/mnt//domains/concept/html/temp3/ on line 18

Comment: Aww just realized the code you gave me was in old unsecure Mysqli... Please, my code is in PDO. dont switch it up on me.

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq `mysqli` isn't insecure/old. `mysqli` and `pdo` are current drivers that can be used with a `mysql` DB, (either could be used insecurely).

Comment: @chris85 perfect way to safe land the best answer to his comment / statement. Was avoiding an argument over which is safer.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use a foreach? That way you don't have to worry about handling iterations and possible infinite loops that while loops have.

Also, I personally prefer not to make function calls and assignments in a while/foreach.. It's not that big of a deal to add 1 extra line just before the declaration. Will improve readability and make it easier to debug your code.